# Why some classes cannot be constructed?

Tags: apex, class, date

when I started learn Apex, I was confused, because I cannot create date instance like:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

I had to use static method

```
Date date = Date.newIstance(...);
```

So, why i must use static method and cannot use constructor?

Answer (score 3):

The `new` syntax is used for classes that have [constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm). The keyword is the means by which you call a constructor for the class, but not all classes necessarily have constructors. Some classes are static or only have static methods. A common example of a class like that in Apex development are Lightning component controllers which typically only have static, `@AuraEnabled` methods and no constructors.

If I had to guess, the reason for not using a Date constructor is because Dates would have several, similar constructor method signatures. Among the methods that return new Dates there are:

- `newInstance` - which takes 3 Integers
- `parse` - which takes a String
- `valueOf` - which takes a String or an Object, and because `Object` is the root type of other primitive Objects in Apex, it can be a number of things including another `Date` or `DateTime`.

Expressing those methods as constructors would leave you with the following signatures:

```java
Date(Integer, Integer, Integer)
Date(String)
Date(String)
Date(Object)
```

You end up with overlap in the latter three signatures because they all accept the same type of argument (in Apex, `String` is an `Object`). Also, the intent of a method like `parse` is different than the intent of a constructor. `parse` can take a variety of strings and do its best to parse them into a Date. With `valueOf`, you had best have a string that can convert cleanly to a Date or you may run into trouble.

If you're new to object oriented (OO) programming I would suggest reading over the [Classes, Objects, and Interfaces documentation for Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes.htm) which talks about constructors, the `static` keyword, objects, and classes. For general information on object oriented programming StackOverflow has good Q&As that are more general for OO languages.